# How to write a Gentoo ebuild file , with LINGUAS support

Tags: linux, gentoo

I wanted to write a ebuild for some binary package , it contains a folder for different languages , its structure is:

> ls /path/po:

```
de  fr  ja  zh_CN  zh_TW
```

I think it's easy to do it , but the document provided by Gentoo is really limited , how can i filter the unnecessary language files ? I shouldn't be copying all those to /usr/share/locale.

==========================================================

@Updates:

I discovered a simple method , which examines ${LANGUAS} variable ,
like the following code:

```
insinto /usr/share/locale
for x in "${LANGUAS}";do
  if [[ -d "po/${x}" ]];then
    doins "po/${x}"
  else
    einfo "LANGUAGE $x is not supported by this app"
  fi
done
```

Just wondering if it's official approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an official approach as it is very package dependent.  For example, some packages may require additional parameters to be passed to ./configure while others, like your, require a more manual approach.

As for your example above, I believe it to be perfectly acceptable.  You haven't provided the whole ebuild so just remember that you need to be adding the acceptable languages into the IUSE var.

e.g.

```
LANGS="de fr ja zh_CN zh_TW"
for X in ${LANGS} ; do
    IUSE="${IUSE} linguas_${X}"
done
```

For a more complicated example you could check out the [openoffice-bin ebuild](http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/app-office/openoffice-bin/openoffice-bin-3.3.0.ebuild?revision=1.15&view=markup)